# How to navigate to a specific array position when clicking an item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a RecyclerView in my Android application, and I want to enable the user to click on an item within the RecyclerView. Upon clicking, I would like the user to be navigated to a specific position within an array that corresponds to the clicked item.

I have already implemented the RecyclerView and have an array of items in my activity. However, I'm unsure how to synchronize the item position in the RecyclerView with the array index in the activity.

```
package com.DeepDolphin.narutosongsoffline

import android.media.MediaPlayer
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.os.postDelayed
import com.DeepDolphin.narutosongsoffline.R
import com.DeepDolphin.narutosongsoffline.adapters.seasonOneItems
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MusicPlayer : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var songNameTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var singerNameTextView: TextView
    lateinit var playButton :FloatingActionButton
    lateinit var pauseButton :FloatingActionButton
    lateinit var stopButton :FloatingActionButton
lateinit var songSeekBar: SeekBar
   private  var mediaPlayer : MediaPlayer?= null
    private var isPlaybackStopped = false



    private val MusicArray = ArrayList<seasonOneItems>()

    private var currentIndex = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_player)

        MusicArray.add(
            seasonOneItems(
                R.string.opining_one, R.string.singer_one, R.raw.rocks
            )
        )
        MusicArray.add(
            seasonOneItems(
                R.string.opining_two, R.string.singer_two, R.raw.wind
            )
        )
        MusicArray.add(
            seasonOneItems(
                R.string.opining_two, R.string.singer_two, R.raw.opning3
            )
        )
        val currentSong = MusicArray[currentIndex]

        MusicArray[currentIndex]

        // Initialize views
        songNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.music_player_song_name)
        singerNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.music_player_singer_name)
        playButton = findViewById(R.id.play_button)
        pauseButton = findViewById(R.id.pause_button)
         stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop_button)
        songSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.song_seek_bar)
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, currentSong.song)


        // Set initial song
        updateSongData()

        // Handle button clicks
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.previous_song_button).setOnClickListener {
            playPreviousSong()
        }

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.next_song_button).setOnClickListener {
            playNextSong()

        }
        controlSound (currentIndex)

    }


    private fun updateSongData() {
        val currentSong = MusicArray[currentIndex]
        songNameTextView.text = getString(currentSong.SongName)
        singerNameTextView.text = getString(currentSong.SingerName)
        if (mediaPlayer == null || mediaPlayer?.isPlaying == false) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, currentSong.song)
            inisilazeSeekBar()

        }
        mediaPlayer?.seekTo(currentIndex)

            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, currentSong.song)

    }

    private fun playPreviousSong() {
        if (currentIndex > 0) {
            currentIndex--
            mediaPlayer?.stop()
            mediaPlayer?.reset()
            mediaPlayer?.release()
            mediaPlayer = null
            updateSongData()

        }
    }

    private fun playNextSong() {
        if (currentIndex < MusicArray.size - 1) {
            currentIndex++
            mediaPlayer?.stop()
            mediaPlayer?.reset()
            mediaPlayer?.release()
            mediaPlayer = null
            updateSongData()


        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
    }





fun controlSound(ind:Int) {
    playButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer?.start()
updateSongData()
        }
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (mediaPlayer !== null) mediaPlayer?.pause()

    }
    stopButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (mediaPlayer !== null) {
            mediaPlayer?.stop()
            mediaPlayer?.reset()
            mediaPlayer?.release()
            mediaPlayer = null
        }
    }

    songSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            if (fromUser == true) mediaPlayer?.seekTo(progress)

        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }

    })

}

 fun inisilazeSeekBar(){
     mediaPlayer?.let {
songSeekBar.max = mediaPlayer!!.duration
     val hander = Handler()
     hander.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
         override fun run() {
             try {

                 songSeekBar.progress = mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition


                 hander.postDelayed(this, 1000)
             } catch (e: Exception) {
                 songSeekBar.progress = 0
             }
         }

     },0)


 } }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
    mediaPlayer?.stop()
        mediaPlayer?.reset()
        mediaPlayer?.release()
        mediaPlayer = null
    }
}
```

```
package com.DeepDolphin.narutosongsoffline.adapters

import android.content.Intent
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.DeepDolphin.narutosongsoffline.MusicPlayer
import com.DeepDolphin.narutosongsoffline.R
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SeasonOneAdapter(val SeasonOneArray: ArrayList<seasonOneItems>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SeasonOneAdapter.SeasonOneViewHolder>() {
    inner class SeasonOneViewHolder(SeasonOneItem: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(SeasonOneItem) {
        val SongName = SeasonOneItem.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.song_name)
        val SingerName = SeasonOneItem.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.singer_name)
        val seasononecrads = SeasonOneItem.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.season_one_cards)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SeasonOneViewHolder {
        val view = SeasonOneViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.music_cell, parent, false)
        )

        return view
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return SeasonOneArray.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SeasonOneViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentSeasonOneItem = SeasonOneArray[position]

        holder.SongName.text = holder.itemView.context.getString(SeasonOneArray[position].SongName)
        holder.SingerName.text = holder.itemView.context.getText(SeasonOneArray[position].SingerName)
        holder.seasononecrads.setOnClickListener {
         val arrayindex =   SeasonOneArray.lastIndex


        }
}}
//Ps : I'm  so sorry to bother i feel guilty posting here
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll want to separate your list from the "do this thing with an item" code. That means you have your `Adapter` (which takes data you pass to it and displays it inside a `RecyclerView`) and then a handler of some kind that takes care of events you can trigger by interacting with the list, like tapping a thing, deleting an item, etc.

A typical way to do this in Kotlin is to add a property that holds a function you supply, like this:

```
// inside your adapter
var itemSelectedHandler: ((Item) -> Unit)? = null
```

If you're not familiar with that syntax it might look a little weird, but the type is `(Item) -> Unit`, i.e. a *function* that takes a single `Item` parameter, and returns `Unit` (or doesn't return anything, if you like). Then it's wrapped in parentheses to add the `?` and make the whole thing nullable - you could also pass this in the `Adapter`'s constructor and make it a non-null requirement, whichever way works for you!

(I'm also calling the item type `Item` so it's clear what it is. Your list contains items whose type is `seasonOneItems` which is a little confusing for a single item - ideally you'd call that `SeasonOneItem` but that's up to you)

---

Then when you need to handle a click, you just invoke that function with the appropriate item:

```
holder.seasononecrads.setOnClickListener {
    itemSelectedHandler?.invoke(currentSeasonOneItem)
}
```

So whatever function has been passed in, you're calling it (if it's not null) with the item the clicked `ViewHolder` represents.

And you can set up that handler function in the `Activity`, say with a lambda:

```
// when you initialise your RecyclerView with an instance of `SeasonOneAdapter`
adapter.itemSelectedHandler = { item ->
    // do something with the selected item
}
```

That lambda is where you actually write the code to handle the click. The adapter basically says "hey, this item was clicked in the list - here you go, enjoy" and this is where you do something with it. The adapter doesn't need to know anything about what happens with that `Item`, it just passes it to the function. Something else (the `Activity` in this case) takes it from there.

---

Notice I'm not passing an index here - you *could* (i.e. passing `position` that's provided to `onBindViewHolder`), but that can get messy, because you're relying on keeping two separate data structures from different parts of the app in sync. You're relying on a number in the adapter having the same meaning somewhere else in the app - and even if you handle that, it's brittle and easy to break.

So instead, I'm passing the `Item` itself. You could also pass another piece of data, like a unique ID, something that should be consistent everywhere. That way, if you need to know where something is in a data structure (like another list) you can just search for it.

But often, you just want to fetch the item itself - and in that case, you already have it! The adapter passed it to you. In your case, you just want the resource IDs to play a song, right? It's right there in the passed `Item`, so you can just use it directly. You might want to, say, write a `playSong(song: Item)` function that will load the correct audio file and play it, display the title etc. Then you can call that from your handler function, but also from the prev/nextSong functions too - just fetch the next song from your list, and call `playSong` with it. (If you do need to find `item` in your list, so you know which index is currently playing, you could call `indexOf(item)` to find it.)

---

Hope that helps make sense of things! You haven't posted all your code (like setting up the adapter) so I don't know exactly what you're doing, but hopefully that gives you some idea of where to go. And hey, maybe you do just want to pass the index if you're sure you're using the same list in both places - if it works for what you're doing (e.g. if you have to look up the index anyway) just go with what's easiest. And don't feel guilty for posting questions! That's what the site's here for - heck you posted code as text, in code blocks, you're already doing well